# Shape TierListView Scrolling Problem

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a tierview that uses a shape xml file for the background.

```
Drawable greyGradient = 
    this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.grey_gradient);
final TierListView tierView = (TierListView) findViewById(R.id.content_list);
tierView.setBackgroundDrawable(greyGradient);
```

My problem is that whenever I scroll the list my Stroke around the edges of the TierListView disappears. Actually the entire xml file stops working until the scrolling stops. When I release the touch the stroke returns. How do I keep the stroke and just cause the list items to scroll within it?

```
<shape    
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
   android:shape="rectangle" >    
<corners              
   android:topLeftRadius="5dip"        
   android:topRightRadius="5dip"        
   android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"        
   android:bottomRightRadius="5dip" />   
<gradient        
   android:angle="90"              
   android:endColor="#000000"             
   android:startColor="#3d3d3d"       
   android:type="linear" />       
<size        
   android:scaleType="center" />      
<stroke        
   android:width="2dip"        
   android:color="#d6d7d6" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I fixed the problem by changing android:layout_weight="1" to 5.  I don't know why this would make a difference (the documentation is bare on layout_weight) but it did.